# ClassNotFoundException when including Library Project (Eclipse,Andrdoid)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github, classnotfoundexception

I have downloaded an android project from Github.
**https://github.com/lemonlabs/ExpandableButtonMenu**

It is an ExpandableButtonMenu library.

There is a demo activity also provided for seeing it in action.
But,whatever I tried, I dont seem to have got the app to run(it compiles, and crashes).
**I am using Eclipse Juno.**

Here is Exactly what I have done:

1. Extract the Download Zip.
2. Go to File->import->Android->Existing Android Code into workspace
3. Browse for the extracted folder.
4. After that, TWO projects are visible for selection(one is the demo, and one is the library     project)
5. Select both
6. Mark the library project as library from properties->islibrary
7. Right Click on the demo project->properties->Android->Library->Add the library project from step 4.

   I also tried going to the build path of the demo project and adding the library project to the build path.

The code returns NO errors, and it compiles, but the app crashes with the following error:

```
>  05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{lt.lemonlabs.android.samples.expandablebuttonmenu/lt.lemonlabs.android.samples.expandablebuttonmenu.DemoActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> lt.lemonlabs.android.samples.expandablebuttonmenu.DemoActivity 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
> 05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
> 05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
> 05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-04 10:28:15.264:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-04 10:28:15.264:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
> 05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592) 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-04 10:28:15.264:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3639): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> lt.lemonlabs.android.samples.expandablebuttonmenu.DemoActivity 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
> 05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 05-04
> 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1025)
> 05-04 10:28:15.264: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
```

Edit::
Java Build Path Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: did you tried taking the jar in to `libs` folder and `add to build path`

Comment: @ViswanathL its a library project and must be referenced. No need to add jar

Comment: @raghunandan, If there is jar you can try that also. its not restricted to library only.

Comment: @ViswanathL Library project must be referenced.

Comment: Did you import sample demo project??

Comment: @Raghunandan no import => failed compilation => impossible to get __run-time__ exception

Comment: @harvey_slash post the java build path screen shot for the demo project

Comment: @Raghunandan
I think I have, because it showed 2 projects while importing. 
one is called main, another is called DemoActivity

Comment: @kirilloid i asked whether op imported the demo project to run not about class imports

Comment: @Raghunandan I have uploaded the screenshot

Comment: @harvey_slash the libraries protion?

Comment: @harvey_slash do you see any java files under the src folder after you import both projects to eclipse

Comment: @Raghunandan no, i dont. 
src folders are empty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51960/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-harvey-slash)

Comment: @kirilloid check my post it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem in java build path.

1. Downloaded the zip file. Extracted.
2. Imported both the projects to Eclipse. Made Main as Library project.
3. Referenced `Main` and `AppCompat`
4. Ran the project

There are no java files in the src folder

Copy the java files from the link for both the library project and the DemoActivity

or

The java files exist under the java folder. Copy the same to your source folder src/

Then download this

https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids

and reference the same in your main library project

[image]

You are done and can run the project

[image]

[image]

Finally

[image]

Comment: I am using api level 17 and not 19. 
also, when i go to extras->android->v7 and export appcompat, i get a project called appcompat, and not android-support-v7-appcompat.
and in that project there are error signs(red cross) in res->v11 and res->14

and the app still does not run

Comment: @harvey_slash both are same.

Comment: @harvey_slash join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51960/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-harvey-slash will help you get it running